# Java how to count first letters of every word in a file

Tags: java

Basically what the title says. I'm having a lot of trouble doing that.
Is there a simple way to do it using charAt? I've tried this so far

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(theText, " /n");    

            String word = st.nextToken();

            char firstChar = word.charAt(0);

            if(theText.charAt(0) == 'a')
            {
                a++;
            }
```

Comment: There is. but what have you tried? SO is to help you with your code, not create code for you.

Comment: I didn't think it was worth posting the code because it seems so wrong, but I did.

Comment: Okay, you seem to read the read line character by character. Try this: read the *whole line*, then `split()` the string on the spaces (Google it). The first element of the array is the first word. It's a `String`, so simply get it's `length()`.

Comment: Either than or find the `index` of the first space, so you can get the length.

Comment: That should at least give you ideas on an easier way to get the length of the first word.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map for this purpose.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StudentBean {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        String thisLine = null;
        try {
            // open input stream test.txt for reading purpose.
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:/test.txt"));
            while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] wordsArray = thisLine.split(" ");
                for (String word : wordsArray) {
                    char firstChar = word.charAt(0);
                    // if map contains that character, increase counter
                    if (map.containsKey(firstChar)) {
                        map.put(firstChar, map.get(firstChar) + 1);
                    }
                    // if map does not contain that character, add that
                    // character with counter = 1
                    else {
                        map.put(firstChar, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `scanner.hasNext` for each word, as opposed to `scanner.hasNextLine` which would skip through each line of the file.

Comment: check my modified code implemented by using BufferedReader.

Answer (score 0):

The scanner will split the words up for you, so there is no need to split the string as suggested in some of the comments. You can simply write

```
    Map<Character, Integer> charCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();        
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("This is a sentence.");

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        char firstChar = scanner.next().charAt(0);

        if (charCount.containsKey(firstChar)) {
            charCount.put(firstChar, charCount.get(firstChar) + 1);
        }
        else {
            charCount.put(firstChar, 1);
        }
    }

    // Print out each of the values.
    for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry: charCount.entrySet()) {
        char character = entry.getKey();
        int count = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(character + ": " + count);
    }
```

Please note that this will count uppercase letters and lowercase letters separately. If you want to count them as the same, you should change

```
        char firstChar = scanner.next().charAt(0);
```

to

```
        char firstChar = scanner.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
```

Comment: I've never used maps before, haven't been taught it yet. If I have to use it i'll do it, but I'd be more comfortable using charAt if I could.
How do I print the results of this map anyway?

Comment: The Map isn't a replacement for `chatrAt`-- the map allows us to match the char with a number. For example, we can call `charCount.get('A')` and it would tell us how many of the letter A there was. You can, if you prefer, make 26 int variables, and write `a++`, but it's generally neater to use a Map.

Comment: I've added a bit to show you how to print out the values as well. Make sure you import `java.util.Map.Entry;`